# Selenium controlled Chromium process hidden by (user32.dll) ShowWindow will still appear sometimes

Tags: .net, selenium-webdriver, chromium, user32

We have a WPF (.NET Framework 4.7.2) application that parses a government site for information (and downloads documents) using Chromium (116) with Selenium (4.10.0). We keep that Chromium process hidden with [ShowWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showwindow).

One of the things we do is download documents. On most pages we click a link to download, which fetches the document with JS and works fine. However on at least one of the pages the download is done by opening a new tab, which causes the Chrome process to be shown.

So how do we stop that from happening?